# Preventing more than 3 threads from reaching sem_wait()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I'm trying to solve a thread synchronization problem for an exercise where the semaphore represents a road. This road can support up to 3 cars going in the same direction at a time and starvation should be avoided. So far, my code below seems to avoid starvation by changing the active direction when the road empties. However, it looks like more than 3 cars/threads can reach the sem_wait() line before numOfCarsOnRoad is updated to be non zero. This means (as you can see in the output), that sometimes, the road is filled with 3 cars, and once they start leaving, the extra ones that managed to reach sem_wait, keep on entering and when they are done, then the direction change takes effect. I'm having a hard time understanding how I can prevent more than 3 cars/threads from reaching the sem_wait line and instead wait.

The logic I'm trying to implement is that up to three cars can enter the semaphore (not always 3, depends on how many reach that point before state variables are updated), then any cars going the other direction will need to wait until the active direction changes and any more cars going in the same direction, will need to wait until their direction becomes active again in another round.

Can somebody point me in the right direction or point out to me where my logic is flawed?

nr.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "nr.h"

sem_t sem;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
unsigned int numOfCarsOnRoad = 0;
unsigned int carsGoingW = 0;
unsigned int carsGoingE = 0;
unsigned long numOfCars = 0; // used for thread initializations
char currActiveDir;          // either W or E
bool currDirInitialized = false;

void *crossBridge(void *i)
{
    int id = *((int *)i);
    char direction[5];
    if (rand() % 2 == 0)
    {
        strcpy(direction, "West");
        carsGoingW++;
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(direction, "East");
        carsGoingE++;
    }
    if (!currDirInitialized)
    {
        currActiveDir = direction[0];
        currDirInitialized = true;
    }

    while (currActiveDir != direction[0] || numOfCarsOnRoad != 0)
        sleep(2);

    sem_wait(&sem); // enter critical region
    printf("Car #%d waiting to pass to the %s...\n", id, direction);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    numOfCarsOnRoad++;
    printf("Car #%d going to the %s. Number of cars on the road = %d\n", id, direction, numOfCarsOnRoad);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    sleep(1); // cross the road

    if (direction[0] == 'W')
        carsGoingW--;
    else
        carsGoingE--;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    numOfCarsOnRoad--;
    printf("Car #%d crossed to the %s! Number of cars on the road = %d\n", id, direction, numOfCarsOnRoad);
    if (numOfCarsOnRoad == 0) // avoid starvation
    {
        if (currActiveDir == 'W' && carsGoingE > 0)
            currActiveDir = 'E';
        else if (currActiveDir == 'E' && carsGoingW > 0)
            currActiveDir = 'W';
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&sem);

    free(i);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void parseCarArg(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0)
        {
            if (++i < argc && strlen(argv[i]) > 0)
                numOfCars = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10); // convert to long
            if (numOfCars == 0)
            {
                perror("You must enter a number of cars > 0!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    parseCarArg(argc, argv);
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the generator using epoch time in millis

    if (sem_init(&sem, 0, 3) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to initialize semaphore!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to initialize mutex!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t cars[numOfCars];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++)
    {
        int *id = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *id = i;
        if (pthread_create(&cars[i], NULL, crossBridge, id) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to create threads for the cars!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    // wait for all threads to finish
    for (i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++)
        pthread_join(cars[i], NULL);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

nr.h:

```
void * crossBridge(void *i);
void parseCarArg(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

and a sample output with -c 20 as input:

```
Car #0 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #0 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #1 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #1 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #1 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #0 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 0
Car #2 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #2 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #2 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 0
Car #18 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #18 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #17 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #17 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #4 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #4 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #4 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #9 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #17 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #5 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #18 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 0
Car #9 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #5 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #16 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #16 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 3 <-- example of where the issue occurs
Car #9 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #5 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #11 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #11 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #8 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #8 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #16 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #19 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #19 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #11 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #8 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #3 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #3 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #6 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #6 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #19 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #12 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #12 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #6 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #3 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #7 waiting to pass to the East...
Car #7 going to the East. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #12 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #7 crossed to the East! Number of cars on the road = 0
Car #15 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #13 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #15 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #14 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #14 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #13 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 3
Car #13 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 2
Car #14 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #15 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 0
Car #10 waiting to pass to the West...
Car #10 going to the West. Number of cars on the road = 1
Car #10 crossed to the West! Number of cars on the road = 0
```

Comment: Your question's title captures the solution:  if you must use a semaphore to represent the bridge's capacity, then you need another synchronization point before you reach the semaphore.  I know you are constrained _a priori_ in the tools you must use, but [John Bollinger is quite right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066453/132382):  a counting semaphore is a very poor fit for this problem.  I suspect we're either missing something about the permitted solutions, or your teacher has a wrong-headed idea about how to solve this.

Comment: @pilcrow Thank you for your comment. I'm just having a hard time understanding how to synchronize the threads before the semaphore and after the two while loops. I'll give it another go. As for the permitted solutions and the approach, sadly I haven't left anything out. These are the constraints they've put in place for this exercise. They mentioned that it's so that we learn how they work but I guess that their correct use isn't their top priority. Just the functionality that they want us to see sadly

Answer (score 0):

A semaphore is the wrong tool for this job.  Whatever additional logic you might put in that limits the threads arriving at the semaphore to a certain number could as easily be used to eliminate the semaphore altogether in favor of a simple counter.

You mention condition variables, but do not show any in your code.  CV + mutex should be your general-purpose pattern for synchronization problems involving shared state, such as the number of cars waiting to proceed in a particular direction, or the number that have passed through since that direction was opened.  Sometimes a semaphore is sufficient, but your case is more complex than that.

Your code is more complex than I care to analyze or rewrite for an SO answer, and I'm not inclined to do your homework for you, but here's an outline of a solution:

- there are shared variables recording

  - the current direction of travel on the bridge
  - for each direction, a queue of waiting cars
  - the number of cars presently on the bridge (could be modeled by a semaphore, even if that's unnecessary in a general sense)
  - the number of cars that may enter the bridge before traffic can be stopped on account of cars waiting to come the opposite direction.
- there is a mutex used to protect all of the above
- there is a condition variable, used in association with the mutex to make threads wait until conditions are correct for them to proceed.
- when a thread arrives at the bridge, it locks the mutex and checks whether it can enter the bridge.  Either way, it updates the state variables appropriately.
- If it cannot proceed onto the bridge, a thread enqueues itself on the appropriate queue and blocks on the condition variable. When it resumes, it checks again whether it can proceed onto the bridge.
- when a thread exits the bridge, it locks the mutex, updates the state variables appropriately, and broadcasts to the CV.

Comment: Hi there, let me clarify. First and foremost, the semaphore is a must for the exercise otherwise I wouldn't be using it. Secondly, by condition variables i mean the state ones, I have no pthread_condition_t vars. I'll word it differently! Lastly, I appreciate your comments and I'll study them but in no way do I want anyone to "do my homework" for me. I'm asking for guidance or a hint in case I need to shift my thinking process. If you consider any of the above "doing my homework" for me, then by all means don't waste your time helping someone like me. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail, although it is perhaps contrary to the spirit of the exercise, you still could use a semaphore to represent road capacity despite the additional synchronization needed making that superfluous.  And you *do* need additional synchronization of some kind to achieve the stated goal.